# Combination of Zigbee and Bluetooth 4.0

Tags: bluetooth, zigbee

Is there any product with a combination of both Zigbee and Bluetooth 4.0 protocols? If not is it possible to design a module with such combination?

Answer (score 3):

There is at least one module announced, which combines Bluetooth, ZigBee and WiFi protocols:

The [RedPine M2MCombo RS9113](http://www.redpinesignals.us/Technologies_&_Chipsets/Chipsets/RS9113.php) module combines dual-band 802.11n + BT4.0 + ZigBee into an SoC.

The module was announced in early April 2013, and is available for sampling to qualified companies.